# Looking up Gift Card Codes in Checkout outside of totals.phtml

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

In Magento Enterprise, the "remove gift card" link in the cart sits in the total.phtml file. I would like to move this code to the block.phtml file so I can make it a text link based on our revised cart layout. If I move the code over as-is I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getGiftCards() on a non-object
```

The line in question is

```
$_cards = $this->getTotal()->getGiftCards();
```

and I know the issue is that the getTotal() part of the object call is not recognized. If I bring it to

```
$_cards = $this->getGiftCards();
```

the page will load with no error but the gift card code is not passed. What is the proper object I should be calling here to get getGiftCard() to work or is there a different way for me to get all the gift cards attached to a quote in the block.phtml file? Just to clarify, this is the Magento Enterprise Gift Card module and not the unirgy gift card module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use `getCards()` Helper class?

```
$cards = Mage::helper('enterprise_giftcardaccount')->getCards($this->getOrder());
```

Comment: CLoser but now I get this error: Call to a member function getGiftCards() on a non-object in app/code/core/Enterprise/GiftCardAccount/Helper/Data.php on line 37

Comment: You are supposed to call "getCards" maybe?

Comment: I don't think so because this line is pulled out of the class of GetCards. My feeling is that I need the equivalent Mage::helper call for getTotals().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $_cards = Mage::getModel('enterprise_giftcardaccount/giftcardaccount')->getGiftCards();
```

Comment: Does the same as $_cards = $this->getGiftCards(); No error but no results either.